# search data with multiple values in django

Tags: python, django, search, filter

Want to filter data with multiple values in django.Currently i can only take two value from html but only one value filtering

**This is my *views* code**

```
   p = request.GET.getlist('passout',[])
   c = request.GET.getlist('course',[])
   s = request.GET.getlist('skill',[])
   
   search_variables = {}

   if p:
       for l in p:
           search_variables['passout__yearofpassing__contains'] = l
           print("@@@@@",p)
   if s:
       for j in s:
           search_variables['skill__skill_name__contains'] = j
   if c:
       for k in c:
           search_variables['course__course_name__contains'] = k
           print("@@kk",k)

   datas_list = Student.objects.filter(
       **search_variables, status="Active").order_by('id')
```

**This is *html* code**

```
                     <div class="col col-sm-3" style="margin-right:-80px;"> 
                                <select class="selectpicker" id="passout" name="passout"  placeholder="Select YOP" multiple >
                                    {% for j in p %}<option value="{{ j }}" selected>{{i.yearofpassing}}</option>  {% endfor %}
                                            {% for i in yr %}
                                                <option value="{{i.yearofpassing}}">{{i.yearofpassing}}</option>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col col-sm-3" style="margin-right:-80px;" >
                                <select class="selectpicker" name="course" id="course" placeholder="Select Course" multiple >
                                    {% for j in c %}<option value="{{ j }}" selected >{{i.course_name}}</option> {% endfor %}
                                    {% for i in cr %}
                                        <option value="{{i.course_name}}">{{i.course_name}}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>    
                            </div> 
                            <div   class="col col-sm-3" style="margin-right: -350px;">
                                <select class="selectpicker" id="skill" name="skill" placeholder="Select Skills" multiple >
                                    {% for j in s %}<option  value="{{ j }}" selected  >{{i.skill_name}}</option>{% endfor %}
                                    {% for i in sl %}
                                            <option value="{{i.skill_name}}" >{{i.skill_name}}</option>
                                     {% endfor %}
                                </select>    
                            </div> 
                            <button id="search4" style="margin-left: 320px; " class="au-btn  btn-info btn-sm" >Search  </button>
                            <button id="search" style="margin-left: 1px; " class="au-btn  btn-info " > <a href=" {% url 'publicpage' %}" style="margin-left: 8px; height: 40px; color: white;"  title="Reset"> <i style="font-size:medium; margin-bottom: 1px; " class='fas fa-sync'></i></a></button>
```

[image]

in this image i search student with year of passout 2019 it shows a result

[image]

if i search with two or three values it shows nothing but in db the students are present

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that you don't have that data for all search filters because Django filter work with `AND` operator and in your image you said give me a result that happened in `2019 AND 2020` and this is not possible.

the filter is working you just need to store the right data.

Comment: ohhh ok... there is any way to filter with list

Comment: Do you mean with `OR` notation?

Comment: i was storing search data in a  dict. If the key have two values then the values in a list like {key:['value1, value2]}. So any way to filter with lists

Comment: you will keep every thing the same but you will use Q operation check out the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects.         don't forget to UP my answer ❤️